# How to combine the texts in subfolders with Python

Tags: python, subdirectory, os.walk

I have a folder containing 4 subfolders and want to combine the texts in each of the subfolders (In others words, the production should be 4 combined texts respectively but not a whole text unifying all the subfolders).
[The folder is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JEGC.png)

I want to use *os.walk* but have no result.

the code is below:

```py
import os
rootdir=r'xxx\xxx\xxx'

allfiles = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):

    for d in dirs:
        f_out = open(rootdir+d + 'combined.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        for file in files:
            allfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))

    for i in allfiles:
        if i.endswith(r'.txt'):
            f_in=open(i, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
            for line in f_in.readlines():
                f_out.write(line)

            f_in.close()
            f_out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you walk (through a storm)...

You'll need to log the files to the directory they were found in - as it is, when you get to your f_out.write() line, your way out of sync with what was happening on your reading loop.

Try this:

```
allFiles2 = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):


    for d in dirs:
        f_out = open(rootdir + d + 'combined.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        allFiles2[os.path.join(root,d)] = []
    
    for name in files:            
        fullName = os.path.join(root, name)
        #At this point, we want to send the file to the correct dictionary position, so use the path defining the dictionary as a search item
        for key in allFiles2:
            if key == fullName[:len(key)]:                
                allFiles2[key].append(os.path.join(root, name))
    
for i1 in allFiles2:  #Looping through the keys (directories) in allFiles2
    with open(i1 + 'combined.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
        for i2 in allFiles2[i1]:  #Looping through the files in that directory
            if i2.endswith('.txt'):                
                with open(i2, 'r') as f_in:
                    for line in f_in.readlines():         
                        f_out.write(line)
                    f_out.write("\n")
```

Now, I'm not sure what shape you hope the output text files to be - but hopefully thats a useful starting point for you.